# Odoo, multiple rpc calls to edit one text field. (ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update)

Tags: javascript, python, multithreading, odoo, rpc

I am trying to log everything user does in the custom screen (UI) on point of sale module of the odoo 14 version. When user clicks button the button calls multiple functions and at certain point of these functions I am calling

```
this.rpc({model: bla.bla, method: test_test, args:[rec_id, params]})
```

just to add a line to already existing text field record with id of rec_id.
The python method is just doing a check then if the field has some value it adds w/e in params to its old value or if its empty just set its value to w/e in params.

```
def test_test(self, param):
  if self.text_field:
     self.text_field += param
  else:
     self.text_field = param
```

Maybe because I am calling it too often , I am encountering following error in terminal.
ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

Please help, and thank you for your time.

Although retrying is making the program to work as intended I cannot have too many errors appear in my terminal which will add up to quite a size since its logging whole text field over and over everytime the rpc is called.